# Colombeau product of distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

How can use the Colombeau generalized function method to evaluate the product of distributions
$ \delta (x) \times \delta (x) $ or $ \delta ^{n} (x) \times \delta ^{m} (x) $ (derivatives of dirac delta) or the product $ \delta (x) \times P(1/x) $?

How could I do it?

Comment: one should be a bit careful: while there is a surjective map from the space of Colombeau functions to the space of distributions, but it is *not* injective. There is no *natural* inverse map. You need to say explicitly what you mean by $\delta$ as a Colombeau function - different choices give different results.